# Main source in Visual C++.NET

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

These lines of code allow to run a C++ Winform application:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
   Application::EnableVisualStyles();
   Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

   MyProject::MyForm form;
   Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Could you explain me what is that **[STAThread]**?

And what about this:

```
Application::Run(%form);
```

What does that `%` symbol mean?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> STAThreadAttribute indicates that the COM threading model for the
>   application is single-threaded apartment. This attribute must be
>   present on the entry point of any application that uses Windows Forms;
>   if it is omitted, the Windows components might not work correctly. If
>   the attribute is not present, the application uses the multithreaded
>   apartment model, which is not supported for Windows Forms.

It is equivalent of `CoInitialize` for C++

And `%` is [Tracking Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
It is like reference `&` but in managed code.